# Hashicorp - vault service fails to start

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

I have setup Hashicorp - vault (Vault v1.5.4) on Ubuntu 18.04. My backend is Consul (single node running on same server as vault) - consul service is up.

My vault service fails to start

```
systemctl list-units --type=service | grep "vault"
vault.service                        loaded failed failed  vault service  

journalctl -xe -u vault
Oct 03 00:21:33 ubuntu2 systemd[1]: vault.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
- Unit vault.service has finished shutting down.
Oct 03 00:21:33 ubuntu2 systemd[1]: vault.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 03 00:21:33 ubuntu2 systemd[1]: vault.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 03 00:21:33 ubuntu2 systemd[1]: Failed to start vault service.
-- Subject: Unit vault.service has failed
```

`vault config.json`

```
 "api_addr": "http://<my-ip>:8200",
  storage "consul" {
   address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
    path    = "vault"
  },
```

`Service config`

```
StandardOutput=/opt/vault/logs/output.log
StandardError=/opt/vault/logs/error.log


cat /opt/vault/logs/error.log
cat: /opt/vault/logs/error.log: No such file or directory
cat /opt/vault/logs/output.log
cat: /opt/vault/logs/output.log: No such file or directory
sudo tail -f /opt/vault/logs/error.log  
tail: cannot open '/opt/vault/logs/error.log' for reading: No such file or 
directory


:/opt/vault/logs$ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 vault vault 4096 Oct  2 13:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 vault vault 4096 Oct  2 13:38 ..
```

Comment: What do the vault logs say?

Comment: Updated the main post, cant find the log files!  How do I set log level.

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging, the issue was silly goofup mixing .hcl and .json *(they are so similar - but different*) - cut-n-paste between stuff the storage (as posted) needs to be in json format. *The problem is of course compounded when the error message saying nothing and there is nothing in the logs.*

```
"storage": {
    "consul": {
        "address": "127.0.0.1:8500",
         "path" : "vault"
    }
 },
```

There were a couple of other additional issues to sort out to get it going- `disable_mlock : true`, opening the firewall for 8200: `sudo ufw allow 8200/tcp`.

Finally got done (rather started).